# <EMBED> Tag on iPhone: Not getting the scrollbar

Tags: android, iphone, html

This is my HTML code on .php file in my website

```
<EMBED name="Sample_Name" src="kebabdelight1.pdf" style="width:640px;height:700px;overflow: auto;"></EMBED>
```

This code shows the proper scroll bar on Desktop and laptops browser... but not working on android and iPhone devices. Please help me... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way i found to solve this problem is, by integrating the plugins like ***`scribd`*** or ***`crocodoc`***, to show your documents on websites without caring that which platform on which our site is running on...
Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is nothing you can do about this as its default behavour, but you could try forcing the scroll bar using:

```
 overflow-y: scroll;
```